# Interpretation of multimeter displaying "OL"

Tags: multimeter, terminology

Multimeters normally displaying "OL" when measuring resistance in ohms and the cables are not connected.

My friend told me that apprentices in Germany learn it is "Overload",
while my friend suggested "open load" or "open loop".

I know that in the products we design the diagnostics for a broken wire is "open load", and "open loop" is a term used in control theory. So I opted for "open load."

Can a native speaker please clarify this?

Comment: Pretty sure it is documented in the multimeter manual.

Comment: [Fluke's manuals](https://www.fluke-direct.com/pdfs/cache/www.fluke-direct.com/87-5/manual/87-5-manual.pdf) repeatedly state it as "overload".

Comment: my old manual states 0.L when a measurement range is violated (e.g. also for voltages) - in that case the translation OverLoad is perfect. It also explains to show 0.L also when the measured resistance is to high - so the range is violated also. But there is no "overload" in that case (or does it reference the input amplifier circuit is in saturation?). Fluke Manuals state 0L (zero-L) is "The input is too large for the selected range" and also its displayed when the continuity test / resistance measurement qualifies an open circuit...

Comment: @Unimportant Ah, I overlooked that. you are right

Comment: Specific manufacturers' manuals notwithstanding, I always thought it was "Over Limit".

Comment: @vir *"Over Limit"* seems problematic. One might mistake **OL** as over-the-limit where damage or danger begins - usually far higher than the intended meaning of **overscale**. I would hope that the manual makes clear that seeing **OL** means neither damage nor danger. OP's friend's suggestion of "open-loop" or "open-load" works nicely for **ohmmeter** but fails for **volts** or **amps**, where the **OL** symbol is used too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ***OL*** dates back to the 1970s when the 199.9 mV LCD voltmeter modules first appeared. The displays were seven-segment + decimal points in the format `1.9.9.9` and full scale was 199.9 mV. I built a multimeter using one - I can't remember the manufacturer - and a design from Electronics Today International. The module was very expensive at the time - maybe GBP 25.

The choice of over-range indication was limited to characters which could be generated using the seven-segment displays. Some used `1`    and others the familiar   `OL`. From an electrical point of view it just meant that the module was receiving more than 199.9 mV. The resistance measuring range uses a current source to drive current through the resistor under test and the meter module just measures the voltage drop across the resistor. Measuring across an open circuit will cause the voltage to rise to more than 199.9 mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJALBe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simplified resistance measurement circuit. I1 would be set to \$ \frac {0.2}{range} \$ - so \$ \frac {0.2}{2000} = 0.1 \ \text{mA} \$ for the 2 kΩ range.*

I'm afraid I can't find a datasheet for any of the displays of that time. I suspect that **O**ver**L**oad is as good a guess as any.

---

Cool tip:

The modules are 9 V. The 0 V GND was, if I remember correctly, about 2.5 V below the +9 V input. You could check the state of charge of the battery powering the meter by switching to 20 VDC range and touching the V probe to V+ and V- in turn and subtract the readings. e.g. +2.5 - (-6.2) = 8.7 V battery. This should be possible with most modern meters too.

Comment: You mean use a Multimeter to measure its own battery? I never thought about that one... I will try :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Multimeter's normally displaying "OL" when measuring resistance in Ohm and the cables are not connected.

Some do, some have other over-range indications.

> I know that in the products we design, the diagnostics for a broken wire is "open load", and "open loop" is a term used in control theory. So I opted for "open load"

I don't think this is a good interpretation.

While open leads on a resistance range is the most common time you will see the over-range indication, it's not the only time. You will also see it if you have the meter locked on a particular range and probe something that is too high current/voltage/resistance for the range or if you probe something that is beyond the abilities of your meter to measure.

Answer (score 1):

[Fluke 87 Manual, Page 15](https://assets.fluke.com/manuals/87______umeng0800.pdf), refers to OL as "overload". The manual is consistent throughout with this convention, reiterating it in other places. Here is the description copied from the manual:

> **OL Overload Indication.**
> Displayed on digital display when input (or math calculation in REL mode) is too large to display. If you are taking duty cycle readings, OL is displayed if the input signal stays high or low. All segments are illuminated on analog display.

Answer (score 0):

User @Transistor's answer is perfect, but for what it's worth, here's another perspective on the subject.

A digital ohmmeter and ammeter can both be considered voltmeters. When measuring resistance, the current is fixed and known, and the meter is measuring voltage across the device under test, and when measuring current, it is really measuring voltage across a known sense/burden resistance. In all cases, the measurement being taken is some voltage.

From this perspective, "OL" is simply the condition that the voltage being measured exceeds whatever ADC is able to convert (with required accuracy), an "overload" condition.

My pendantry doesn't deal well with modern meters saying "over-load" for resistance exceeding some maximum, a condition that is clearly ***under***-load, so I just pretend that the "L" means "limit" instead of "load". Then I can get on with the rest of my life.